# How to detect 'leave' button on window.onbeforeunload js php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm developing a simple LMS system for my project. The code below will block user if they leave the current exam page and it will pop out js message if user wants to leave the page (has 2 button leave and stay)

[comfirmExit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zByrd.png)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var hook = true;
  window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    if (hook) {
      return "You have attempted to leave this page. Are you sure?";
   //if leave --> markzero.php
   //else stay --> do nothing
    }
  }
  function unhook() {
    hook=false;
  }
</script>
```

What I want to implement here is that - if user click 'leave' the mark will be given as 0. I'm not sure how to detect that 'leave' button.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
               window.onbeforeunload = function() {
                   var Ans = confirm("You have attempted to leave this page. Are you sure?");
                   if(Ans==true)
                       return true;
                   else
                       return false;
               };
</script>
```